# How to read each column value from uploaded excel (xls or xlsx) file in python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, python-3.2

I am uploading an excel sheet (.xls or .xlsx format). After uploading the file I want to read value of each column.

My html is

```
<form id = "ListForm" name = "ListForm" action = "" method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>PM List</td>
<td><input type="file" name="file_pm" id="file_pm" ></td>
</tr>   
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="pmUpload" id="pmUpload" class="button"></td></tr>       
</table>
</form>
```

Python code is

```
def pmUpload(request):
    data = request.FILES['file_pm']
    # here I want to iterate through each column & rows in excel.
```

Can anybody suggest the method to iterate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` python library.

```
file = open('file.xls')
csvreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
for r in csvreader: # iterates each row
    print r         # r is a list of column of that row.
```

Hope it helps.